# Stubbed my toe... which preposition?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request, phrase-choice

How to say table was the thing I kicked into using *stub?*

Is it one of these?

> **A**. I stubbed my toe **by** the table?
>
> **B**. I stubbed my toe **onto** the table?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On

> I stubbed my toe on the table

But I’m assuming it was the table leg? So if you want to be more specific:

> I stubbed my toe on the table leg

Comment: The leg is understood, as it's implausible to stub a toe on the table top. You would have to be doing some kind of kick, and we don't call that "stubbing".

Comment: "I was practicing my roundhouse kicks and crashed into the table!" is one example.

Comment: No @Barmar. It’s very plausible. You might be drilling a hole in the wall and standing on a chair that is level with the table surface. But yes - probably in real life you wouldn’t bother to say table leg.

Comment: Lol I'm trying to imagine someone standing on a chair (a very tall chair, by the way, to be level with the surface) in such a way so as to accidentally stub your toe.

Comment: It’s a tall stool, the table is low and narrow, by the wall. Maybe one you keep plants on. Therefore it’s easy to lean over it to do the drilling, but also easy to stub your toe on it.

Answer (score 34):

**[by](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by)** is used to show the person or thing that does something. You can't really use **by** with a table in this sentence, because it's you that's doing something (kicking the table). You could use **by** about a table if, for example, it fell on you:

> He was killed **by** a table that fell from the roof garden of the hotel.

**[onto](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/onto?q=oNto)** is used to show movement into or on a particular place. for example:

> He climbed **onto** the stage

One of the meanings of **[on](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on?q=oN)** is to show what causes pain or injury as a result of being touched, for example

> I hit my head **on** the shelf as I was standing up

**on** is therefore the correct preposition to use in your sentence.

Comment: _"into"_ would also work for this case, as for a car crashing into a barrier for example.

Comment: While "I stubbed my toe into the table" is certainly understandable, It's not idiomatic and not something I would expect to hear from a native speaker. Using "on" is much more common.

Comment: I think that this should be reordered a bit, when I first saw this answer I thought it was recommending "onto" as the preposition to use. Answering the question in the first line before going into your explanation helps avoid that kind of confusion in my experience.

Comment: @KamilDrakari: the OP's question refers to **by** and **onto**: I have explained why these are not appropriate before suggesting a better preposition.

Comment: *I stubbed my toe* **by** *the table* could also be understood as *I stubbed my toe* **(beside / next to)** *the table*. (In the same way that *I walked* **by** *the table* does not mean that the table is an agent of some kind of action.) But while it *is* usable here, it's not usable in the sense that's been asked in the question itself.

Comment: @JavaLatte re: the order of the answer.  You are right, but so is KamilDrakari.  Maybe a tl;dr at the top?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/stub#unabridged_10) and the [Collins English dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stub#stub__1) you can also use "against":

> I stubbed my toe **against** the step.
>
> I stubbed my toes **against** a table leg.

As commented by other users, this expression is regional: although it would be understood, it wouldn't sound natural in the American Midwest, nor would it in the UK. But in some parts of America it would.

In light of this, I would recommend to use

> I stubbed my toe **on** the table

which seems to be accepted everywhere.

Comment: Against would be understandable, but it's not something a native speaker would say.  It makes sense with some of the other verbs they use ("strike against") but it doesn't sound right for "stub".

Comment: 'against' is most certainly something a native AmEng speaker would say (in addition to 'on'), though it might be regional. "I stubbed my toe against the curb," for example.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Interesting. I've never heard anything other than "on" in British English.

Comment: @random_forest_fanatic Are you British? In that case, and taking into account the other comments and the votes on them, I think I could add a note to indicate that it's only used in American English.

Comment: @FabioTurati Hehe, nope, I'm American, from the midwest.

Comment: "Against" would seem to be regional; I've never heard it in the Northeast.

Comment: We said it back in Baltimore, so mid-Atlantic, possibly.

Comment: Also from midwest US (MN), and can confirm that although this would be understood (the same way "stubbed my toe onto the table" would be), it sounds awkward to my native ear, and would not be the first choice of words.